# Why does my mootools slide instance prevent code, and slides, from being executed?

Tags: javascript, slider, mootools, jsfiddle, rte

I am trying to realize a simple `slideIn()` with mootools on a RTE.
It should slide in, when the RTE area is hovered (`mouseenter`), and show some extra options for writing an entry that I do want to offer in this area. Please see the link below, should be self-explanatory

So my Problem is, when I try to create a `Fx.Slide` instance, the code isnt being executed.
I tried it with the `show` method and it works fine.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABmeP/13/) with my working code, the parts that do not work are commented out.

Again, what I do want is to Slide in the `buttonbar` element when the `mouseenter` event is fired. This works fine with `show` but does not with the slide instance.

I'd be happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

If there are any futher questions, please comment and i will give give further information, if required.

So long,
Lino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just realized what i was doing wrong. It was this little piece:

```
wrap.grab(buttonbar.hide());
```

This is rubbish, because `buttonbar` is not in the DOM already. It has to be split up to:

```
wrap.grab(buttonbar);
buttonbar.slide('hide');
```

After that, it just took a few changes in the event setting:

```
editor.addEvents({
    'click': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        buttonbar.show();
    },
    'mouseenter': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        this.addClass('mark');
        buttonbar.show();
        //this.slideIn();
    },
    'mouseleave': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        //buttonbar.hide();
        this.removeClass('mark');
    }
});
```

to this:

```
editor.addEvents({
    'click': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        buttonbar.slide('toggle');
    },
    'mouseenter': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        this.addClass('mark');
        buttonbar.slide('in');
    },
    'mouseleave': function(ev) {
        ev.stop();
        this.removeClass('mark');
        buttonbar.slide('out');
    }
});
```

And now my slides slide as hell :))
Here a link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABmeP/20/).